# The "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted" message should also mention error logs

Tags: feature-request, quality-improvement

A comment on a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57654805/why-is-my-onclick-not-working-in-my-react-project) mentioned that the instructions on how to fix unformatted code were unclear. I tried opening the editor and un-indenting the error message, and got this warning:

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

From what I can tell of the user's comment, they only realized through trial and error that the "uncommented code" referred to was the stack trace. Please change the above prompt to also indicate that error logs should be formatted as code.